# How to make a working read from file Function?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    char a[100][100];
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    FILE* file = fopen( "A:/input.txt", "r" );
    if( file == NULL ){
        perror( "Error opening file !\n" );
    } else {
        while( ! feof( file )){
            fscanf( file, "%d;%s\n", &i, a[i] );
        }
    }
    for( ; k < i; ++k ){
        printf( "%d -> %s\n", k, a[k] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have this working piece of code and i tried to implement it as a function like this:

```
int reader(char b[20], char *a[100][100], int *i){
    int j = 0;
    FILE* file = fopen(b, "r" );
    if( file == NULL ){
        perror( "Error opening file !\n" );
    } else {
        while( ! feof( file )){
            fscanf( file, "%d;%s\n", j, a[j] );
        }
    }
*i = j;
return 0;}
```

and make a call from main:

```
char a[100][100];
int i = 0;
reader("Type.txt", &a, &i);
```

but when i use the function, code crash at fscanf call.
Any ideea how can i make this work or how can i create a function that reads line by line from a file and creates an array in this form: array[0] = firstline, array[1] = secondline, etc.

Comment: There are a myriad problems here. `char *a[100][100]` in the `reader()` interface is probably not what you want or mean; you are then not using it correctly. The design will only read up to 100 lines and only if each line is less than 100 characters long. The `while (!feof(file))` notation is a (bad!) hangover from Pascal programming; it is not good C code, ever. You don't check the return values from `fscanf()`. You don't increment `j` in the scan loop, so you keep on overwriting the same line. You don't close the file you open in `reader()`. In `main()`, you don't increment `i` in the loop.

Comment: In the file that i am reading the data is store like this id;name and that is why i dont increment i becouse i read it from file directly, i read the id and put the name in array[id].

Comment: You can't do that.  The value of `j` used to index `array` is determined before the `scanf()` is called.  You then update `j` with the read.  The next input goes into the index read for the previous input.  I did wonder whether that's what you were trying, but I thought "no, it can't be that, can it?"  How many warnings are you getting from your compiler?  You should be getting some from the `reader()` function (I get two: `format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’` and `format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 4 has type ‘char **’`).

Answer (score 1):

You did it correctly in your `main()` function with the variable `i`, but when you moved it to a function you forgot a symbol. You need to pass the address of `j` to `fscanf()`:

```
fscanf( file, "%d;%s\n", &j, a[j] );
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to add the `&` to `j` in this line

```
fscanf( file, "%d;%s\n", j, a[j] );
```

it should be

```
fscanf( file, "%d;%s\n", &j, a[j] );
```

also the input array of the function should not contain asterisk `*`

```
int reader(char b[20], char a[100][100], int *i){
```

Comment: thanks, best solution! if i only add & at j tries to put the data in 4 bytes and writes one entry at 4 positions in string a so removing * is necessary.
Thanks again!